# JavaScript: The Good Parts Names/Strings railroad diagrams confusing

Tags: javascript

I started reading JavaScript: The Good Parts book and became confused at first pages (7 and 9 if be exact) by the railroad diagrams.

There are diagrams for the name and the string literal. (you can see the diagrams [here](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/syntax-diagrams.html))

As I know names in JavaScript can start with letters as well as with underscore or even '$' symbol. Following by the book's diagram it can starts only from letters.

For the string literal, imagine that you want to represent string like that: "\\".
Following by the diagram it's not possible(seems like after the "escaped character" the "any unicode character except " and \ and contol" is required.

Are those an errors in the book? Or I miss something?

Comment: Here is the list of confirmed errors in the book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596517748

Comment: The language described in the book "The Good Parts" is not JavaScript but a subset of it - you can call it "Crockford's JavaScript". Crockford introduces new syntax restrictions. One of those restrictions is that names cannot start with `$` or `_`...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: that would make a good answer...

Comment: @Marco Mariani Thanks, there is a confirmation on error in the string literal diagram.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: That really makes everything clear. Thank you. Could you post your comment as answer so I'll be able to accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The language described in the book "The Good Parts" is not JavaScript but a subset of it - you can call it "Crockford's JavaScript". Crockford introduces new syntax restrictions. One of those restrictions is that names cannot start with `$` or `_`.

Comment: Good lord! I could have gone 150 more pages thinking it was supposed to be actual JavaScript!

Comment: A subset of JavaScript is technically still JavaScript ;-)

Comment: @Šime_Vidas Ambiguous wording, sorry. So: _Good lord! I could have gone 150 more pages thinking it was supposed to be standard/raw JavaScript!_

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the name railroad diagram definitely has problems.  As you say, a name can start with underscore, but the diagram precludes it, and dollar signs seem to be completely missing.

You're wrong about the string literals though, since `"\"` is properly not allowed.

One for you, one for Crockford.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript literal names may start with letters, digits, underscores, or dollar signs. However, it's a convention to use only letters as the first character. http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

The string literal may have any escaped character (e.g. `"\""` or `"\\"`) or any other character save the delimiter (`"` or `'`) and the backslash (`\`). The escaped character is not a single backslash. It's the representation of the whole escaped character. See the **escaped character** rail diagram in your own link.