# How to choose OO design patterns for JavaScript

Tags: javascript

By OO I mean classical OO.  I keep going back and forth between defining my "classes" ( javascript does not have traditional classes ) using the module pattern to provide privacy and using object literals to create a collection of "public statics".

I have no guiding force when I create "classes" that lets me determine what type of organization to use.  Well, besides the fact that my code passes both jshint and jslint w/ no options set.

I'm working w/ about 1500 lines of code so I need  a "guiding force" before the code becomes un-manageable and I have to scrap it.

I am well aware of the different ways to write "classes" in JavaScript.  Those taught by JavaScript Web Applications written by Alex MacCaw as well as the numerous ways listed here on SO.

However, application wise, I just don't know what method to use.

The simplest seems to be a collection of methods and variables in an object literal like this:

```
var public_statics = {
    public_func: function () {},
    public_var: "hello"
}
```

and the most complicated seems to be - an IIFE.

```
(function(){
    var private_var;
    function private_func(){
    }
})();
```

How do I know which one to use or the multitude of in-between variations?

For a concrete example: How about for a controller in the MVC.

Currently ( and some what randomly chosen), I implement a controller like this:

```
var Co = {};
Co.Controller = function(){
    // 'classes' from Mo are called here
    // 'classes' from Su are called here
}
```

then I tack on other Control related method to Co.

How do I choose what style of OO to use?

---

**Updated**

My library is currently divided between 4 namespaces:

```
var Mo = {},
    Vi = {},
    Co = {},
    Su = {};
```

Model, View, and Controller should be self-explanatory and (Su)pport is for all "classes" not contained in the MVC, for example DOM access, Effects, Debug code, etc.

What OO style should I use to further organize this library/code?

**Controller "Class" example:**

```
/**
 **  Controller
 */

Co.Controller = function (o_p) {
    var o_p_string_send;
    Su.time();
    o_p = Mo[o_p.model].pre(o_p);
    if (o_p.result !== 'complete') {
        o_p_string_send = JSON.stringify(o_p);
        Su.time();
        //Su.log(o_p_string_send);
        Co.serverCall('pipe=' + o_p_string_send, function (o_p_string_receive) {
            Su.time();
            //Su.log(o_p_string_receive);
            o_p.server = JSON.parse(o_p_string_receive);
            Mo[o_p.model].post(o_p);
            Su.time(true);
            Su.log('Server time: [' + o_p.server.time + ']');
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Not having anywhere near the SO score you have makes me worried that my opinion is uninformed, but isn't the main argument for OO design for code reuse?  Maybe with a hint of maintainability for single use but complex applications?  In JavaScript you have a choice, so the answer can be more complex

Comment: ... good question, I'm faced with the same dilemma and the hardest part is letting JS be JS and not try to beat it into behaving like Java (or such). I try to go by namespacing and 'keeping it simple'

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Are you using classes so you can benefit from inheritances?

Comment: The example is for a Controller which in this case, does not use inheritance.  The question has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: Do you ever use the "new" keyword in your code or are all objects build from plain objects like in your example?

Comment: You might look into the work on instantion and inheritable Javascript classes John Resig has done here http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ and here http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/.

Comment: @vector - it seems academic as well...I mean some of the JavaScript experts ( Resig, MacCaw, Crockford ) use it in this way.  Just verified on Google.  I think the concern is, is that is is done in so many different ways...unlike a language which directly supports classical OO where the approach is more defined.

Answer (score 2):

`IFFE`s are often confusing to read and personally, I have no idea why they have become so mainstream. I think code should be easy to read and concise. Attempting to simulate language behavior that is not part of the language specification is often-times a very dumb idea.

For example, JavaScript does not support multiple inheritance, polymorphism, or many other interesting paradigms. So a lot of times, we see people trying to create these crazy ways of sorta'-kinda' having polymorphism or private members, etc in JS. I think this is a mistake.

I'm currently working as a sort of hobby project on a high-performance JS data structures library (I'm trying to outperform Google's closure and a bunch of others). Coming from a C++ and Java background, I always like to make stuff classes and I like inheritance, etc, etc. Let me share some code-snippets with you. At first, I thought I was being clever because I was writing stuff like this:

```
function __namespace(n, v) {
    return {"meta":{"namespace":n,"version":v}};
}

var FJSL = FJSL == undefined ? new __namespace("Fast JavaScript Library", 0.1) : FJSL;

__using = function(parent, child) {
    clazz = new child();
    clazz.super = new parent();
    if (clazz.super == undefined) return clazz;
    for (a in clazz.super) {
        for (b in clazz) {
            if (a == "constructor" || b == "constructor") continue;
            if (clazz[b] === clazz.super[a]) continue;
            if (a == b && typeof clazz[b] != typeof clazz.super[a]) throw "Typesafety breached on '" + a + "' while trying to resolve polymorphic properties."; 
            if (a == b && typeof clazz[b] == typeof clazz.super[a]) {
                clazz["_"+a] = clazz.super[a];
            } else if (clazz[a] == undefined) {
                clazz[a] = clazz.super[a];
            }
        }
    }
    return clazz;
};
```

And I was using it like so (in the example of a simple Queue):

```
FJSL.Array = function() { 
    this.data = [];

    this.contains = function(idx, element) {
        for (var i = idx; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            if (this.data[i] === element)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    this.size = function() {
        return this.data.length;
    }
}

FJSL.Queue = function() {
    return __using(FJSL.Array, 
    function() {
        this.head = 0;
        this.tail = 0;

        this.enqueue = function(element) {
            this.data[this.tail++] = element;
        };

        this.dequeue = function() {
            if (this.tail == this.head)
                return undefined;
            return this.data[this.head++];
        };

        this.peek = function() {
            return this.data[this.head];
        };

        this.size = function() {
            return this.tail - this.head;
        };

        this.contains = function(element) {
            return this._contains(this.head, element);
        };
    }
)};
```

You'll note how I'm sort of faking inheritance (a Queue uses an Array, har har, I'm clever). However, this is absolutely insane to **a) read** and **b) understand**. I couldn't help but be reminded of this meme:

[image]

Let me show you functionally equivalent code without me trying to do all this fancy pre- and post-processing:

```
FJSL.Queue = function(opts) {
    this.options = opts;
    this.head = 0;
    this.tail = 0;
    this.data = [];
};

FJSL.Queue.prototype = {
    add : function(element) {
        this.data[this.tail++] = element;
    },

    enqueue : function(element) {
        this.data[this.tail++] = element;
    },

    dequeue : function() {
        if (this.tail == this.head) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return this.data[this.head++];
    },

    peek : function() {
        return this.data[this.head];
    },

    size : function() {
        return this.tail - this.head;
    },

    contains : function(element) {
        // XXX: for some reason a for : loop doesn't get JIT'ed in Chrome
        for (var i = this.head; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            if (this.data[i] === element) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },

    isEmpty : function() {
        if (size) {
            return true;
        }
        return false
    }, 

    clear : function() {
        this.data = [];
    }
};
```

Obviously, I'd have to duplicate the prototype constructor for any other structures that may use an array, but what I'm trying to accomplish is  so much clearer, even a novice JS programmer can tell what's going on. Not only that, but if people want to modify the code, they know exactly where to go and what to do.

My suggestion is don't get caught up in the insanity of trying to make JS behave like C++ or Java. It's never going to. And yeah, you can fake inheritance and private/public/protected members, but JS was never intended for that. I think the repercussion of having this kind of bloated code (that attempts to simulate non-standard behavior) is very taxing on high-performance web-apps and their ilk.

In short, I suggest using an object literal:

```
var public_statics = {
    public_func: function () {},
    public_var: "hello"
}
```

It's easy to understand, easy to modify, and easy to extend. If your system is brittle enough to crash and burn if someone accidentally changes some "private" variable, you simply need to document it.

Comment: What about for the in-between...such as constructor functions....`var constructor_function = function(){ // private stuff }`, this provides a natural language construct for privacy and instances via `new constructor_function`?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: I think that's a very appropriate approach. Constructor functions are a part of the language and even though they may be a bit more difficult to understand, do provide a slightly OOP-oriented approach to objects. Heavy constructors can negatively impact performance, however, especially when (if) trying to simulate inheritance, etc.

Comment: It does seem strange that there is no way to group together prototypes with their correlative objects...for example. `var InstanceBased = function(){}; InstanceBased.prototype = {};` It seems this is where the language began to digress a bit from a classical OO syntax, as well as classical OO functionality, as they are public by default not private.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: what Douglas Crockford talks about in his book is a subset of JS (in which he has some extra syntax restrictions), see this question for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759800/javascript-the-good-parts-names-strings-railroad-diagrams-confusing

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the IIFE simply because you can make methods private.  Otherwise, you will have to do some sort of weird convention with underscores.

Furthermore, stylitically, if you encapsulate it within a function, you have the *option* of making semicolons - its plain old javascript.  Requiring each line in the object literal to end with a comma seems funny to me.

Comment: At over 1500 lines, can I choose to use IIFE for all my "classes"?  Do I need to worry about increased processing to immediately execute?

Comment: I believe so.  Also as a personal choice, I write my classes in separate files just like in Java.  I use a tool like node.js's grunt to concatenate/minify the files together for distribution.  As a slight tangent, you might wish to look at require.js which encapsulates your modules in addition to making them both browser and node compatible.  It may bring you a bit closer to a familiar-Java development environment (if that is your goal).

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript the language itself is implemented in many different ways, i.e. it is different for each browser, you already have to begin with inconsistency.

JavaScript does not directly support classical inheritance. ( It supports prototypical inheritance ).

For my needs I will choose not to implement classical inheritance.  This is not ideal b.c. classical inheritance allows you to directly implement best practice OO - encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism.

However I prefer to wait until the language directly supports OO via classical inheritance or similar.

In the mean time I will just use the basic prototypical inheritance to help enable code re-use.