# Communication between scripts | Three methods

Tags: javascript

How do I properly communicate data betweens two scripts.

In this particular case I have an element in one script, but I want to append it in another script.

The simplest way I could do this is by using the global window object as go-between.

But globals are not best practice.

What is the correct way to pass this element to another script?

Both script are encapsulated in the module pattern.

**Script 0 Create Element Point**

```
var element = document.createElement( "div" );
element.innerHTML = response_text;
```

**Script 1 Append Element Point**

```
Vi.sta = {

    // implemented in the boot loader - shared global space - appended child already - you don't have to append until now.
    // Static data has already been composed. 
    // Pull off window and append or best practice

};
```

Both are encapsulated in the module pattern

```
(function(){ 
    // the code here 
})()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All JS scripts are run in the global scope.  When the files are downloaded to the client, they are parsed in the global scope.

So if you've got

```
// File_1.js
var myObj = { colour : "blue" };
```

There's nothing stopping you from doing this:

```
// File_2.js
var otherObj = { colour : myObj.colour };
```

As long as File_1.js is loaded before File_2.js

If you are namespacing, ie: `MYNAMESPACE = {};` and each file extends your namespace through modules (rather than "module pattern" referring to returning interfaces from immediately-invoking functions), then check for the module's existence.

If you ARE writing modules for a namespaced app, and you DO need access to variables from one module to another, then you should be providing an `interface` for that.

If you are `SANDBOXING` modules, then you need to provide them all a `proxy` similar to a `service-locator` or a `"registry"`, or develop a `messaging-system` based on a `mediator-pattern`.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist   You didn't mention ***which*** module pattern.  Are you talking about `revealing-module`, are you talking about `namespacing` or are you talking about `sandboxing`?  Because all three have very different levels of workaround.  Because we have absolutely no way of knowing which it is, we have no way of knowing which workaround is correct.

Comment: lots of good key words for me to Google - thanks I will look into this .

Comment: This module pattern -> (function(){})() -> supports global imports and of course I can return from it.

Comment: That's not a module.  That's an immediately-invoking anonymous function.  It's perfect for setting things up, and running them, but it's meant for self-contained code, which will not survive outside of itself, unless it's returning a value/object/function to the outside world.  In `namespacing` you might go: `MYPROJECT = (function(){}());` and that immediate-function would return all of the ***MODULES*** as an object, so that `MYNAMESPACE` can be used in your site, to do things.  jQuery does this, for example.  Then, extra modules are added as members of namespace: `MYNAMESPACE.Media=(...);`

Comment: Actually you left off expression - IIFE - here is a tutorial

Comment: jQuery does not use the method you say it does...review the code.

Comment: Yes.  But it assigns `window.jQuery` and `window.$` all of the exact-same features that would be returned to `var jQuery = ();` Their purpose for doing it inside of the function is expressly to avoid namespace-collisions.  Otherwise, there is 100% ***no difference*** between saying `NAMESPACE=();` and `(window.NAMESPACE={});`, beyond the final time the compiler is finished running.  If you want to import into scope (they don't have to be global, they have to be in the outer-scope's chain) that's fine -- but where are you going to store them, if you don't want them to be global?

Comment: So syntax is different but functionality is the same...returning from and Anonymous IIFE goes to no-where land....hmmm.....fascinating....to communicate between two script there must be atleast one global...this seems to be proof of that...I had 0 globals up until now....oh fiddlesticks

Comment: The goal is to have a program which is perfectly-encapsulated, so that all features can get all of the data they need, and none of the features they don't.  Many people aim for exactly 1 global -- that's the point of `namespacing` -- so that only the namespace is global, and is unique enough so that nobody else on the page is likely to write to it or overwrite it, unless they're working on a module for it.  If the namespace has a message-system, and a loading-system, then each file could have a `NAMESPACE.add_module(name, function() {});` and that would be enough to extend your object.

Comment: That's easy enough to do, what about internally to that "namespace" what goals are there for different developers( so they do not have collisions with in their mutual environment ) as a subset to different (companies/namespaces i.e. jQuery)....look at this post if you have... time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078812/oo-styles-mvc-design

Answer (score 5):

```
window.sharedSpace = {};
sharedSpace.sharedValue = 'foo bar';
```

That way you only have one global object instead of several.

Comment: I was in the process of writing the same. My only recommendation would be to check for the existence of `window.sharedSpace` before declaring it, just on the off chance that it already exists.

Comment: What about returning from one script and importing into the other...might this be better, as a way to avoid globals?

Comment: The 'returning' part that you talk about will require global `function`s. Which would be going backward.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just pass the element to a function in the module?

```
var module1 = (function () {
    return {
        func1: function () {
            // get your element
            var someElement = ...;

            // pass it to the other module
            module2.func2(someElement);
        }
    };
}) ();

var module2 = (function () {
    return {
        func2: function (someElement) {
            // do whatever you want with someElement
        }
    };
}) ();
```

Comment: Even simpler, why not export the element or an object, and then import it using the global import feature of the module pattern...both ways would work I think.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist i am not familiar with "global imports"

Comment: on you IIFE, the very last `()` if you put a parameter in their it is called a 'global import', it is an optimization from simply using variables in the global scope, now they are imported and the scope look up chain is reduced.

Comment: learned this here - http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Comment: @HiroProtagonist ah, never knew they had a special name, thanks for the info. I'm not sure this would help your case, though, as the variable would be imported as soon as the IIFE is invoked, at which time the `someElement` would not have yet been assigned any value.