# Complete railroad/syntax diagrams for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax

Is there a source to get a full syntax description for JavaScript?

I only found [syntax diagrams for "Crockford-Javascript"](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/syntax-diagrams.html), but not for complete JavaScript.
Sadly, this diagrams are incomplete. For example: [names cannot contain `$` or `_`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759800/javascript-the-good-parts-names-strings-railroad-diagrams-confusing).

Comment: the standard is the source: http://es5.github.io/#A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a grammar that is close to [EcmaScript 5th Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf) (2009) here: https://www.bottlecaps.de/rex/

You will need to download it, but you can use it to generate diagrams here: https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui

Click "Edit Grammar", paste the grammar or use "Load" to upload it, then click "View Diagram".